# how do I install updated packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I have run this command on my ubuntu linux system, now how do I install these updates:

\usr\bin\apt-get -y update

It downloaded the package updates, however how do I proceed to install them now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it didn't. It downloaded updated lists of packages. What you need is

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will download new versions of packages and install them.